# requirejs with existing globals

Tags: requirejs

I have a built library (concatenated, minified and included before require.js) of several globals (jQuery + plugins, constructor functions, etc ). This library is used as a base on which apps are built on top of, with assumed dependencies. i.e, if I include my app scripts after the library, then I can freely use jQuery and constructors without any issues.

For bigger apps I'm considering using requirejs (to manage the different modules within the app), while still using this built library. How might I add existing globals like jQuery to the dependency list in require?

```
<script src="pathto/lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="require.js" data-main="../js/app" type="text/javascript"></script>

requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    }
  },
  // jQuery is already loaded with lib.js, no need for any path...
  path : {
    jquery : 'jquery.js'
  }
});
```

Is this possible? Or should I just continue with assumptions that certain globals will exist within the app modules because lib.js was included before require / the app js?

Using require to load the lib.js is not possible, because it is part of a CMS.

**-- EDIT --**

What about using a named module, and just return a handle on the global object, as that is where the lib content sits anyway?

```
define("lib", function () {
    return this;
});

require(["lib"], function (lib) { 
    // use existing globals found in lib via
    lib.jQuery
    // or simply
    jQuery
});
```

That allows me to follow the require() convention of naming dependencies, rather than assuming.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the exact same thing for my project where I load jquery from a CDN, so my path configuration looks like this

```
path: {
  'jquery': '//path/to/the/cdn'
}
```

In your case, I think you should do as you updated (define and then return), because in some 3rd-party libraries, they might define `jquery` as the dependencies. If you don't have `jquery` in your RequireJS configuration, you have to modify the source code of the 3rd party libraries